# How to change a computed property using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

So I'm trying to have the background of my website change when a user does something.

The initial background is set in css:

```
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("'../../gallery/image1.png");
  display: flex;
}
```

So I tried this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("container")).getPropertyValue("background-image") = 'url("'../../gallery/image1.png")'
```

But I get an error saying the property I'm trying to change is read only.

I've tried looking online and the only things I've seen to change the background image does it like this:

```
document.getElementById("container")).style.backgroundImage = 'url("'../../gallery/image1.png")'
```

However, the when I try this the backgroundImage is undefined and not the one I set.

Does anyone know if I can change the computed background-image part of the css?

Comment: You have an extra `'` after `url("`. Get rid of that. Don't you get a syntax error from it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `'` and `)`. This should work:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../../gallery/image1.png")'
```

Comment: Ah bless you, you king